# Как создать запрос MySQL "ALTER TABLE много мерный"?

Tags: mysql

Нужно в БД таблицы поменять в нескольких местах дату. Запрос сделал, все работает. Пример:

**

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_id_posts` 
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' ;
```

**

Но таких таблиц много, у которых есть несколько полей с датами, что нужно поменять.

Нужна помощь в создание запроса, который будет пробегаться по таблицам и формировать мульти запросы как в примере выше.

Как один запрос сделать знаю, а вот как два, нет. Пока не нашел в инете решения, продолжаю искать, если подскажите буду благодарен.

Comment: Получите список таблица-поле из INFORMATION_SCHEMA, курсор, формирование текста запроса, выполнение (prepared stmt).

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для этого используют точку с запятой:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` 
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' ;
ALTER TABLE `table2` 
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  CHANGE COLUMN `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' ;
```

Ещё вариант написать скрипт, который будет автоматически формировать запрос для каждой таблицы.

Comment: Пытаюсь узнать, как написать, автоматический скрипт, который формирует столько CHANGE COLUMN сколько DATETIME в таблице!

Comment: Запрашивайте метаданные таблицы. На их основе наверняка можно получить список нужных полей.